# Is there a way to install globalmenu on lxde or openbox?

Tags: globalmenu, openbox

Is there a way to install gnome-globalmenu on openbox ?

I love minimal linux distro and apps, I don't want to use gnome or kde ...

Answer (score 2):

The easy way, If you want, you can install a plugin of Lxde panel like [here](http://home.student.utwente.nl/j.vanderhoff/downloads/LXglobalmenu.png)

lxpanel is in bottom of screen

The package is [here](http://home.student.utwente.nl/j.vanderhoff/downloads/)

Comment: While this can solve the question, please post the step by step instructions

Comment: I think that link is dead, but (same?) files can be found [here](http://aduteca.adunanza.net/User:bruce_wayne), cf. [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2046754). Also notice that this applet requires globalmenu-server, cf. [this](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4D70FA8D.3010400%40gmail.com&forum_name=lxde-list).

Comment: Has anyone got this working successfully? @UriHerrera